# Geom_bar compared with geom_text with two discrete variables

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, geom-bar, geom-text

I am having two discrete variables (Extract:)

```
Mitarbeiter <- c('0-10', '10-50', '50-250', '250+','10-50', '50-250', '250+', '250+', '0-10')
Behandlung <- c('E-Mail', 'Telefon', 'TV',  'Email', 'Telefon', 'TV', 'Email', 'TV', 'TV') 
Daten <- data.frame(Mitarbeiter, Behandlung)
```

I already created a graph with geom_bar:

```
ggplot(Daten, aes(x = Mitarbeiter, fill = Behandlung)) +
  geom_bar(position="fill")+
  labs(title="IT-Sicherheitsumgang nach Mitarbeiteranzahl", x="Mitarbeiter", y="prozentualer Anteil") + # legends
  coord_flip()+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("snow2","lightblue","skyblue3","#2A5DA3","darkblue"))+
  theme_bw()
```

Now, I would like to add the number of TVs, phones and Emails for a specific Group of Mitarbeiter to the plot.
I tried to use different versions of geom_text but it is not working for me.

Do you know a solution?
Thank you!

Comment: `0-10, 10-50`, etc should be between quotes. The same goes for `E-Mail, Telefon, TV`. Edited.

Comment: Are `'E-Mail'` and `'Email'` the same?

Comment: Oh yeah I forgot to add the "" here in stackoverflow sorry. Email and E-Mail are the same yes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

Mitarbeiter <- c('0-10', '10-50', '50-250', '250+','10-50', '50-250', '250+', '250+', '0-10')
Behandlung <- c('Email', 'Telefon', 'TV',  'Email', 'Telefon', 'TV', 'Email', 'TV', 'TV') 
Daten <- data.frame(Mitarbeiter, Behandlung)

ggp <- Daten %>% count(Mitarbeiter,Behandlung)

ggplot(ggp,aes(Mitarbeiter,n,fill=Behandlung)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity",position = "fill") + 
  geom_text(aes(label=n),position = position_fill(vjust = 0.5))+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("snow2","lightblue","skyblue3","#2A5DA3","darkblue"))+
  labs(title="IT-Sicherheitsumgang nach Mitarbeiteranzahl", x="Mitarbeiter", y="prozentualer Anteil") +
  coord_flip()+theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: @LouisaFritz you are welcome dear, please just accept the answer!!! Kind regards!!!